# How to retrieve selected values of all drop-downs present in a container using JQuery/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Using Javascript, I am dynamically generating dropdowns list under dvContainer. I want to get selected values of all the select elements under that container. The following is HTML code generated from javascript:

```
<div id="dvContainer">
   <div>
      <select id="QType_id2">
         <option value="1">MCQs</option>
         <option value="2">Short Questions</option>
         <option value="3">Long Questions</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="Remove">
   </div>
   <div>
      <select id="QType_id">
         <option value="1">MCQs</option>
         <option value="2">Short Questions</option>
         <option value="3">Long Questions</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="Remove">
   </div>
   <div>
      <select id="QType_id">
         <option value="1">MCQs</option>
         <option value="2">Short Questions</option>
         <option value="3">Long Questions</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="Remove">
   </div>
</div>
```

This Java Script is used to add dropdowns in dvContainer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function AddDropDownList() {

            //Build an array containing Customer records.
            var customers;

            $.getJSON(href="URL GOES HERE",function(customers){
            

            //Create a DropDownList element.
            var ddlCustomers = $("<select />");
            ddlCustomers.attr('id',"QType_id")
            //Add the Options to the DropDownList.
            $(customers).each(function () {
               var option = $("<option />");

                //Set Customer type in Text part.
                option.html(this.type);

                //Set id in Value part.
                option.val(this.id);

                //Add the Option element to DropDownList.
                ddlCustomers.append(option);
            });

            //Reference the container DIV.
            var dvContainer = $("#dvContainer")

            //Add the DropDownList to DIV.
            var div = $("<div />");
            div.append(ddlCustomers);

            //Create a Remove Button.
            var btnRemove = $("<input type = 'button' value = 'Remove' />");
            btnRemove.click(function () {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });

            //Add the Remove Buttton to DIV.
            div.append(btnRemove);

            //Add the DIV to the container DIV.
            dvContainer.append(div);
        });
        };
        
    </script>
```

Using AJAX/jQuery, I want to build a function, which gives selected values of all the dropdowns.

Comment: `QType_id` id should be unique, you can use class instead.

Comment: Which changes should I do in Java to assign different ids to new entries? Sorry for asking this basic question.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the note, it is not good practice to add multiple elements with same id. Suggested is to replace `ddlCustomers.attr('id',"QType_id")` with `ddlCustomers.attr('name',"QType_id")`. Added below is code snippet to get all row data.

```js
function getAllRowsData() {
  var alldata = $('#dvContainer>div').map(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
    data = {};
    data['QType_id'] = $this.find('[name="QType_id"]').val();
    return data;
  }).toArray();
  $("#alldataop").text(JSON.stringify(alldata));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvContainer">
   <div>
      <select name="QType_id">
         <option value="1">MCQs</option>
         <option value="2">Short Questions</option>
         <option value="3">Long Questions</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="Remove">
   </div>
   <div>
      <select name="QType_id">
         <option value="1">MCQs</option>
         <option value="2">Short Questions</option>
         <option value="3">Long Questions</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="Remove">
   </div>
   <div>
      <select name="QType_id">
         <option value="1">MCQs</option>
         <option value="2">Short Questions</option>
         <option value="3">Long Questions</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="Remove">
   </div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="getAllRowsData()" value="Get Data">
<div id="alldataop"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. I will follow your suggestions.